# Updating my APIGW deployment with Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-api-gateway

I understand the title looks weird, but I'll do my best to explain it. Right now, my APIGW deployment looks like this:

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "apig" {
  body = "${file("../json-resolved/swagger.json")}"
  name = "apig"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_deployment" "apig_deployment" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.apig.id

  triggers = {
    redeployment = sha1(jsonencode(aws_api_gateway_rest_api.apig.body))
  }

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}
```

Now, the API itself has some variables, for example, the AWS Function URI: region, account_id and stage variable (environment). The way I did that before was by using:

```
aws apigateway put-rest-api --rest-api-id $Gateway_ID --mode overwrite --body fileb://$Build_SourcesDirectory/json-resolved/swagger.json
```

```
aws apigateway create-deployment --rest-api-id $Gateway_ID --stage-name $ENV --variables environment=$ENV
```

How do I do the same with Terraform?

Answer (score 1):

Create an [aws_api_gateway_stage](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp%20%20/aws/latest/docs/resources/api_gateway_stage) in Terraform. Define the environment variables in the `aws_api_gateway_stage`. See the first example in the [aws_api_gateway_deployment](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp%20%20/aws/latest/docs/resources/api_gateway_deployment) documentation, which includes an `aws_api_gateway_stage`.